# Alternative proof to $M$ maximal $\iff R/M$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, ideals, alternative-proof

This is a long-winded way of proving the theorem. I restate the original statement as

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, then $M$ is maximal $\iff R/M$ is a quotient ring containing only 2 ideals, itself $R/M$ and the zero ring $\{ M \}$.

I am proving this without the use of

1. That $R/M$ is a field
2. The correspondence theorem or any thing to do with the isomorphisms.

I do not want to use those facts.

> $(\Leftarrow)$ Now assume $M$ is maximal relative to $R$ where $R$ is
>   a commutative ring with unity. We need to show $R/M$ contains only two
>   trivial ideals, the zero ring $\{0 \}  = \{ M \}$ and itself $R/M$. Consider the principal ideal generated by the element $\{a + M\}$ with $a\not\in M$. That is, $J = R/M\{a + M\} = \{ra + M\}$
>   Now the ideal $ra + M \supset M$, but $M$ is maximal, so $ra + M = R$. This means $J$ cannot exist. So there cannot be any ideal in between the containment.
>
> $(\Rightarrow)$ Now assume the quotient ring $R/M$ contains two
>   ideals: $\{ M \}$ and $R/M$ itself, and if there is an ideal $K$ of
>   $R$ such that $$M \subset K \subset R,$$ then there is an $k \in K$
>   where $k \not\in M$. Now for this choice of $k$ and using the ideal
>   definition on $R/M$ itself, notice  $$(k + M)R/M = (k + M) \{ a + M
>  \}_{a \in R} = \{ka + M\}_{a \in R} \subset \{a + M \}_{a \in R} =
>  R/M.$$
>
> In fact this containment is equality because we are considering the
>   ideal property on the $\textit{whole}$ ring, so $\{ka + M \} = \{a +
>  M\}$. This means $ka - a \in M \subset K$. Hence if for $k' \in K$, we
>   have $-a = k' - ka \in K$. Then $K = R$ and in fact $M$ is maximal.

Answer (score 4):

Really long indeed!

Suppose $M$ is maximal and that $J$ is an ideal of $S=R/M$. Suppose $J$ contains a nonzero element $r+M$. Then $r\notin M$, so $rR+M=R$ and so $1=rx+y$, with $x\in R$ and $y\in M$. Therefore
$$
1+M=rx+y+M=rx+M=(r+M)(x+M)\in J
$$
so $J=S$.

Suppose $S=R/M$ has only the trivial ideals. Suppose $I$ is an ideal of $R$ with $M\subsetneq I$. Let $r\in I$, $r\notin M$. Then $r+M$ is a nonzero ideal of $S$, hence the ideal it generates is $S$. Therefore
$$
1+M=(r+M)(x+M)
$$
for some $x\in R$. This means $1=rx+y$, for some $y\in M$. Since $y\in M\subset I$, we conclude $1\in I$ and so $I=R$.

Comment: But am I wrong? If so where?

Comment: @Hawk For instance, I can't understand what you mean by $(r+M)\{a+M \}_{a \not\in M} \subset \{a + M \}_{a \not\in M}$. And what does “restricting $R$ to the zero ring” mean?

Comment: @Hawk If $R=0$, then $R$ has no maximal ideal.

Comment: @Hawk I'm sorry, but even with straighter notation, your arguments aren't conclusive. For instance $J=\{a+M\}_{a\notin M}$ means nothing at all.

Comment: @http://math.stackexchange.com/users/62967/egreg, I cleaned it the up. I think there should be no confusion now.

Comment: how'd you go from $rR+M=R$ $\Rightarrow$ $1=rx+y$ for some $x \in R, y \in M$?

Comment: @MyMathYourMath It's the definition of $rR+M=\{a+y:a\in rR,y\in M\}$; but $a\in rR$ means $a=rx$ for some $x\in R$, so $rR+M=\{rx+y:x\in R,y\in M\}$. If $1\in rR+M$, then $1=rx+y$ for some $x\in R$ and $y\in M$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate proof: $M \subset R$ is maximal iff $R/M$ is a field.

$\textbf{Proof:}$

First suppose $M \subset R$ is maximal. As $M$ is an ideal, $R/M$ is a commutative ring with $1$ and as $M \neq R$, $R/M \neq 0$ so let $a+M \in R/M$ be non-zero. Consider the ideal

$$I=\{ra+m : \text{some $r \in R,m \in M$}\}.$$

Clear to see that $I \subset R$ is an ideal and as $a \in I$ and $M$ is maximal, $I=R$. Thus $1 \in I$ and one has

$$1=ra+m ; \space \text{some $r \in R, m \in M$}.$$

This holds iff

$$1+M=ra+M=(r+M)(a+M)$$

thus $(r+M) \in R/M$ is a multiplicative inverse for $a+M$ and $R/M$ is a field.

Conversely, suppose $R/M$ is a field. And suppose there exists and ideal $I \subset R$ such that

$$M \subsetneq I \subsetneq R.$$

Let $a \in I \setminus M$ then $a+M \in R/M$ is nonzero and thus it has a multiplicative inverse. I.e,

$$(a+M)(u+M)=1+M$$

for some $u +M \in R/M$ but this holds if and only if

$$1=au-m \in I$$

Thus $I = R$ and $M \subset R$ is maximal. $\square$

Also theres a proof which uses the Fourth isomorphism theorem for Rings.